# не работает onClick на теге <a>

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброго времени суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня не срабатывает событие вообще любое при наличии обработчика на ссылке (теге `<a>`)?

Пробовал по разному

> addEventListener

и

> document.getElementById('id ссылки').onclick = function(){ тело
>    функции  }

даже в **HTMl** писал

> onclick="name_function()"

не работает хоть тресни.

А если вместо тега **`<a>`** повесить событие на **`<input type="button">`** то все замечательно работает. В чем может быть причина?

В консоли никаких ошибок нет, мол браузер говорит, что все ок!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что при клике на тэг `а` происходит переход/навигация на другую (возможно - эту же самую) страницу.

```
document.getElementById('id ссылки').onclick = function(e){
  /*тело функции*/
  return false; // или e.preventDefault();
}
```

или

```
onclick="name_function();return false;"
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.getElementById('id').onclick = function() {
  this.innerHTML = "good";
}
document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.innerHTML = "good";
})
```

```html
<a href="#" id="id">link<a>
<a href="#" id="id1">link22222<a>
```

Comment: и вам спасибо!!!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста